# Maximum sum of all contiguous subarrays of prime length

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was recently asked this question in an interview,

> Given an array of non-negative integers find the
>   maximum cumulative sum that could be obtained such that the length of all the
>   participating subarray is a prime number. I tried to come up with a solution  for this using Dynamic Programming but unfortunately could not.

Eg: If the array is [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,1,2,2] it should return **46** (sum of the subarray **[9,8,7,6,5,4,3]** of length 7 and **[2,2]** of length 2). You cannot combine [9,8,7,6,5,4,3] and [1,2,2] since it would result in a contiguous subarray (idempotency) of length 10 which is non prime.

Can anyone explain how to solve such problems using DP? Thanks.

Comment: Why not 15? [8,4,3] - length is a prime number (3). You didn't say that all elements should be prime.

Comment: Why would you use dynamic programming? It's simply a matter of first finding the largest prime (go backwards from the length of the list), and then the maximum sub array of that specific length, which is a very common problem.

Comment: @user it should contain contiguous elements. Sorry forgot to mention that. Fixed it!

Comment: @ChatterOne can you please provide a pseudo-code? I don't think I understood what you said.

Comment: For a large array I think you'd want to sweep it into a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) before traversing for sums.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with DP? This problem looks like it admits a fairly straightforward application of the DP idea.

Comment: @n.m. The problem is that I couldn't understand how to come up with the recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do:

- take the length of the list and go back until you find a prime number
- get a window of elements and sum them
- check if it's the maximum sum and in case it is, store it
- go to the next window

**This works because of the constraint that all integers are positive**, it would not work otherwise.

Basically something like this (very roughly, in pseudo-python, obviously not tested):

```
input_list = (8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2)
list_size = len(input_list)

while (list_size):
    if (is_prime(list_size)):
        window_size = list_size
        break
    list_size--

max_sum = -1
for i in xrange(0, list_size - window_size):
    current_sum = sum(input_list[i:i+window_size])
    if (max_sum < current_sum):
        max_sum = current_sum

print max_sum
```

Comment: I had incorrectly worded the question and fixed it now. Can you please have a fresh look at it? Thanks.

Comment: Test it with (100,1,1,1,1,100). It will return a single 5-element subarray of sum 104 but the maximum is 203.

Comment: @n.m. That's because the question explicitly says "contiguous subarray".

Comment: It doesn't. It says "a sum of several non-adjacent contiguous subarrays, each of a prime length".

Comment: @n.m. I see now that the question changed quite a lot since my answer. I should probably delete it.

Comment: @ChatterOne please see my comment above. Initially I could not word what exactly I had in mind, so I have updated the question. Please do have another look at it. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (approximately) `O(n * n / log n)` time, `O(n)` space, DP?

Let `f(i)` represent the greatest sum up to index `i` where `a[i]` is either excluded from a contiguous subset or is the last of a subset of prime length. Then:

```
f(i) = sum(a[0]...a[i]) if (i + 1) is prime, otherwise
  max(
    // a[i] excluded
    f(i-1),
    f(i-2),

    // a[i] is last of a subset
    sum(a[i - primes[j] + 1]...a[i]) + f(i - primes[j] - 1) 
      for primes[j] <= i
  )
```

(Summing the intervals can be done in `O(1)` time with `O(n)` preprocessing of prefix-sums.)

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of the recurrence when a[i] is last of a subset? Or better yet, can you please explain how you arrived at the recurrence is layman terms? I did not understand what it signifies. Thanks :)

Comment: @GeT_RiGhT by 'subset', I meant subarray. If a[i] is not part of a subarray, we wouldn't count it as part of the sum so the max sum up to i in that case would be the greater of the max sum up to (i-1) or (i-2). After that, we're in a situation where a[i] could be the last of a subarray of prime length 2 or more. Then we compare those possibilities one by one: if it's length 2, we add to it the greatest sum up to (i - 2 -1), which is f(i-2-1); if it's 5, we add to the sum f(i-5-1) and so on.

Comment: Why are we considering max sum upto (i-1) or (i-2) if a[i]  is not part of the subarray? Also what would be f(0)?

Comment: @GeT_RiGhT if a[i] is not the last of a subarray then the max sum up to i will not include a[i], therefore it will be the same as the previous max sum. We also check (i-2) since there must be a space between subarrays (but at (i-3) a[i] could be the last of a subarray of length 2 so that's where the other check begins). It seems to me that f(0) would depend on whether you consider 1 a prime. I think the usual convention is to start with 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since others have solved the problem for non-negative integers.

But if you have -ve numbers also, then also this algorithm will work. 
I think you have to slightly tweak [Kadane's Algo](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/).

Following are the changes for modified Kadane's Algo. All lines marked ** are changes.

```
Initialize:
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0
   ** MAX_SO_FAR_FOR_PRIMES =0
   ** SUB_ARRAY_SIZE = 0

Loop for each element of the array
   max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
   ** SUB_ARRAY_SIZE = SUB_ARRAY_SIZE + 1 // since a[i] included in subarray, increase sub_array_size
  if(max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0
   **         SUB_ARRAY_SIZE = 0  
  if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
   ** if(MAX_SO_FAR_FOR_PRIMES < max_ending_here && isPrime(SUB_ARRAY_SIZE)) // comparing when SUB_ARRAY_SIZE is Prime.
   **      MAX_SO_FAR_FOR_PRIMES = max_ending_here.    

return MAX_SO_FAR_FOR_PRIMES
```

Basically, take one more variable `MAX_SO_FAR_FOR_PRIMES`, which keeps the maximum sum subarray for prime sized subarray so far.

Also store the `SUB_ARRAY_SIZE`, which stores the size of the sub-array anytime during looping.

Now just compare you `MAX_SO_FAR_FOR_PRIMES` with your `max_ending_here` whenever the `SUBARRAY_SIZE` is prime. And update `MAX_SO_FAR_FOR_PRIMES1 accordingly.

Comment: Sorry. I had incorrectly worded the question. Fixed it! Can I still solve it using Kadane's algorithm?

Comment: I need cumulative sum of all contiguous sub arrays of prime length. Updated the question. Please have a look at it. Thanks